\cs_new:Npn causes illegal unit or measure error while \let doesn't
In the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \foo:nn #1#2
  {
    \makebox[#1][s]{#2}
  }
% \cs_new:Npn \bar:nn #1#2 { \foo:nn #1#2 }
\let \bar:nn \foo:nn
\fbox{\foo:nn {3cm} {a~b~c~d}}\par
\fbox{\bar:nn {3cm} {a~b~c~d}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

If I use \cs_new:Npn instead of \let, it will throw an "illegal unit of measure" error. Why? How can I fix this?

You're missing the braces to the arguments: \cs_new:Npn \bar:nn #1#2 { \foo:nn {#1}{#2} }. But, since you mean \let, you probably really want \cs_set_eq:NN.

Since I miss the braces, \bar:nn {3cm}{...} will pass the single token 3 to \foo:nn as its first parameter and the error occurs. Right? @gusbrs

It will grab the first single token. So, yes, as far as I get it, \foo:nn, when called from \bar:nn, will see the first argument as 3 and the second as c.

Since \makebox is not fully expandable, \foo:nn neither, thus it's better to define \foo:nn by \cs_new_protected:N(p)n.

How to judge that \makebox isn't fully expandable? @muzimuzhiZ

@Stephen Anything that does typesetting isn't expandable.

@Stephen in addition to what egreg mentions, anything that does assignments isn't expandable as well.

It's a problem of TeX syntax:
\cs_new:Npn \foo:nn #1#2 { ... }

is how you define \foo:nn. But when you call it, you need to do
\foo:nn {<argument 1>}{<argument 2>}

and the braces can be omitted if the argument consists of a single token.
In your attempt, from \bar:nn {3cm}{abcd} you get
\foo:nn 3cmabcd

so #1 is 3 and #2 is c, resulting in
\makebox[3][s]{c}mabcd

which is definitely not what you want. With
\cs_new:Npn \bar:nn #1#2 { \foo:nn {#1}{#2} }

you obtain the desired thing.
Observed that \let should not be used where \cs_new_eq:NN is the correct call, let's compare the following calls:

\cs_new:Npn \bar:nn #1#2 { \foo:nn {#1}{#2} }
\cs_new_eq:NN \bar:nn \foo:nn

Are there any differences? Plenty. With the first call, \bar:nn will use the meaning of \foo:nn that's current at call time; with the second call, \bar:nn will use the meaning of \foo:nn current at definition time. So you need to know why you do such a definition and do the appropriate choice. If you're certain that \foo:nn never changes meaning, the two calls are almost equivalent: not completely the same, because with 1 \bar:nn requires one expansion step more than with 2.
Note. I disregarded a few aspect that aren't relevant for the issue, but they're important.

Try and follow the expl3 naming conventions: both \foo:nn and \bar:nn are bad names.

Functions that employ unexpandable functions/macros such as \makebox should be “protected”:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \stephen_foo:nn #1#2 { \makebox[#1][s]{#2} }

would be better.


